# tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information

Tags: ubuntu, conda, tesseract

I am trying to use pytesseract on a conda environment, my OS is ubuntu 22.04. I have installed pytesseract using "conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract" command. But when I am doing
"text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)"
it shows the follwing error:

TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.

What should I do to run it on my conda environment. Do I need to install pytesseract on the base python env of my OS?

Comment: Have you installed tesseract? If you open a cmd console and try tesseract  - - version, should give you the tesseract version.

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert the path inside our script, like:

```
import pytesseract 
   
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
custom_config = ' '
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
```